# Replacing a letter within a string - why is function not working?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

the following function is supposed to be replacing instances of 't' with 'a' in a given string input. Not sure why it's not working - suggestions? Cheers

```
const replaceLetter = (str) => {

  let newString = str.split(' ')

  for (let i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < newString[i].length; j++){
      if (newString[i][j] === 't') {
        newString[i][j] = 'a'
      }
    }
  }
  return newString.join(' ')
}
```

Comment: you want replace "t" to "a" within string ?

Comment: yep, that's right.

Comment: Note `newString[i]` is going to be a string value, and those are not mutable. Ie you can't change them by setting a value at an index of the string. You have to make a new string by `replace()` or other methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it better with a regular expression?

```js
const regex = /a/gi;

document.getElementById('result').textContent = document.getElementById('test').textContent.replace(regex, 't')
```

```html
<div id="test">tatatatatat</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript provide a method to replace string

```
    const demo = "tttttaaaaabbbb"
    const regex = /t/gi
    const result = demo.replace(regex, "a")
    console.log(result)
```

read more the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code is that you are trying to replace characters in a strings. You can't edit a string using that method. If you want to use that method, you can simplify the code by splitting the whole string into single characters.

Your Method:
1. Split the string into words
2. Look at each word one by one
3. Search for a "t" in each word individually
4. Convert to "a"
5. Turn the array into a string by array.join();
6. Return string

The first two steps can be simplified by splitting the string into individual characters
1. Split the string into single characters
2. Search for a "t" 
3. Convert to "a"
4. Turn array into string by array.join();
5. Return string

This rendered as code is:

```
const replaceLetter = (str) => {
  //Split string into individual characters and make it editable via index method
  let newString = str.split("");
  //Read each character
  for (let i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
    //Check if it is a "t"
    if (newString[i] === 't') {
      //Replace it with an "a"
      newString[i] = 'a';
    }
  }
  //Convert the array back to a string
  return newString.join();
}
```

That would allow editing of the string's individual characters and replacing instances of 't' with 'a' in a given string input.